# Interested in Collective Programming for the web -- Ruby or Python or PHP?

Tags: php, python, ruby, artificial-intelligence, recommendation-engine

For something like a personal recommendation system, machine learning type of stuff on a website, what language would be best?

Comment: There are just to many variables to be able to reccomend a language for you, please update your question with more info.

Comment: +1 I'm sorry you got senselessly bashed tester2001. I have done a lot of machine learning work over the last years. Off hand I don't recall any machine library or toolkit I used offering PHP/ruby support and certainly not a unified interface to a bunch of different techniques like pythons scikits learn. It's just such advanced stuff not many people can develop it (especially not for free), so the supply is much, much less than the demand. Recommendation engines I have only worked with on a highly custom basis, and I don't know the libraries.

Answer (score 16):

The language you know best would be best.

I mean that half-seriously.  Given the brief description of your project, there's no reason to believe any of the languages you list would be any better or worse than the others.  Those three languages are adequate for approximately similar tasks, so you should pick the one you are most comfortable with and proceed.

Any other recommendations would be advocacy for one language or the other, with no real basis on which to evaluate them.  Your description is just too vague.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Programming Collective Intelligence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325) - Building Smart Web 2.0 Applications
2. [Collective Intelligence in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988312)

Answer (score 0):

All of the points that Bill Karwin have brought up are entirely valid: You should really operate in what you are most comfortable with.

If that isn't a factor, I would personally suggest Ruby. It's an incredibly powerful language that draws a lot of commonalities with Lisp and is probably just as good, if not better, for AI programming for all the same reasons Lisp was: it's an extremely dynamic, self-modifiable language. As an added benefit Ruby has a really nice standard library including some great libs like the distributed computed library "dRuby".

Answer (score 0):

I happen to know a world-class expert in machine learning. He likes Prolog, especially for the higher level logic of the system. Hadn't even heard anyone mention that in a long time. Personally, I like Java. But if you're going to do intensive machine learning, you should be concerned about the speed of math processing. C++ for the math, in my view.

Answer (score -2):

I recently did some research into this for a project at my day job. It was for a recommendation system and the options were php,perl or python.

PHP was out almost immediately, there were no good 3rd party open source libraries and the language itself is not as well suited to any kind of complex real programming.

Python had a few libraries that i wanted to try out and Perl didn't, so I went with Python. In the end, none of those libraries were useful to me but besides library support I prefer python personally anyway so that was the right decision.

Because your question is very vague I can only suggest that you *don't* use PHP and select the language based on library support for your specific problem area and your comfort in that language. I would say that library support is the biggest factor in your decision and language familiarity/preference is a close second.

Comment: There are libraries for virtually anything in PHP. And it's absolutely suitable to write complex applications with it. I suggest some more research before posting such nonsense.

Comment: Developing a large app in PHP ended up frustrating me (though PHP5 makes some huge improvements). However, to say that it has no good 3rd-party libraries is just plain wrong. It doesn't implement library management very well, but everything you need is likely there.

Comment: Matchu, could you tell me a reason of why you were using PHP4 when PHP5 was almost everywhere? Or was it 7 or more years ago?

Comment: Man, I'm sorry you got senselessly bashed Freshhawk (same as OP, apparently). I have done a lot of machine learning work over the last few years. Maybe I missed one, but I don't recall ANY machine library or toolkit I used offering PHP support. It's just such advanced stuff not many people can develop it (especially not for free), so the supply is much, much less than the demand. You have to either be willing to create all your own compatability mechanisms, or go for languages with serious support for the ML stuff you want to do.